# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simple_salesforce'. Works on on-prem machine, but not my local machine

Tags: python, simple-salesforce

I am working on a project that my manager wrote some scripts for. It is our data pipeline where we pull data from Salesforce and other sources. His scripts work using the simple_salesforce library I have downloaded simple_salesforce onto my machine and can see that I have the library, but for some reason whenever I try to run code I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simple_salesforce'
```

When I do it on our on-prem machine it works fine, but no matter how many times I uninstall and re-install the library it won't work for me. I have a hunch it might have something to do with my PATH variables or something, but I don't understand the concept well so please help me understand how I can get my machine to recognize that I have the simple_salesforce library downloaded! Thank you!

Comment: Exactly how are you installing it?  It's likely you have multiple versions of Python, and often `pip` gets you Python 2 when you expect Python 3.  To install it, try the standby `python -m pip install xxxx`, so you use the same Python you're running.

Comment: I tried both with pip and pip3. I will try python -m pip install though and keep you posted on how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: @TimRoberts it didn't work... I uninstalled and reinstalled with that command. Is there any special type of uninstall command I should run? I just ran pip uninstall simple-salesforce.

When I go to the file where simple-salesforce is referenced it gives me this error --> Import "simple_salesforce" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports). Not sure if that helps

Comment: So, you mentioned Pylance, which implies you are using Visual Studio Code.  Are you doing the install/uninstall in the Visual Studio Code terminal?  In some cases, VSCode has its own Python.

Comment: No I was doing it in the terminal on my machine. I will try running it in the terminal in VS Code. I hadn't thought of that. I'll keep you posted on that! Thank you for the help